# Angular change text value from svg object

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to get and set text from svg object.

This is my SVG object

```html
<svg id="svgObject" class='outer' width='500' height='225'>
  <text class='graph-title' x='45' y='100'>I WANT TO CHANGE THIS TEXT</text>
</svg>

<p id="svgContentText"></p>
```

I try this, but i have `[object Text]`

```js
let svgObj = document.getElementById('svgContentText');
let svg = document.getElementById('svgObject');
let oldText = svg.childNodes[0];
svgObj.innerHTML = ("SVG font-size is " + oldText);
```

Comment: maybe you need `svgObj.innerHTML = ("SVG font-size is " + oldText.textContent);`

Answer (score 0):

just put an id to the text:

```
<svg id="svgObject" class='outer' width='500' height='225'>
  <text id="text" class='graph-title' x='45' y='100'>I WANT TO CHANGE THIS TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

then in js file, brief mi perro just get id of text value save it and then change it

```
let svg = document.getElementById("text");
let oldText = svg.innerHTML;
svg.innerHTML = "SVG font-size is " + oldText;
```

or if you want to do by children access:

```
let svg = document.getElementById("svgObject");
let oldText = svg.children[0].innerHTML;
console.log(oldText);
svg.children[0].innerHTML = "SVG font-size is " + oldText;
document.getElementById('svgContentText').innerHTML = oldText;
```

see codepen :

https://codepen.io/jppgit/pen/VwvGQrB

Good vibes!